# 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.) with file that exists

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module

This is the rewrite rule:

```
 <rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
                matchType="IsFile" 
                negate="true" 
                pattern="" 
                ignoreCase="false" />
         </conditions>
       <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Both of the following files exist. One GET succeeds and the other throws a 500.

200

```
GET http://greenearth.game/node_modules/aurelia-leaflet/dist/amd/leaflet.js
```

500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)

```
GET http://greenearth.game/node_modules/aurelia-open-id-connect/dist/amd/open-id-connect-role-filter.js
```

The 500 error specifically is:

> "Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'redirect all requests'".

Two questions:

1. Why is the first file giving a 500?
2. How can we make it a 200?

Putting `<remove name="redirect all requests" />` at the top of the `<rules>` element answers #2 but not #1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like there is another `web.config` that conflicts with your parent one in the `/node_modules/aurelia-open-id-connect/` or its subdirectories `dist` and `amd`.

If detailed errors is enabled, the 500 error must locate the problematic `web.config` file.

Comment: That was 100% it. Well done. The `Aurelia-open-id-connect` plugin does have a web.config with the same rule. I'm amazed at the insight of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If its an angular app, for me, deleting main.js and uploading fresh one solved the issue.

Comment: how is it relevant to question ?